# Batch process for single and double positive particles in Image J

Tags: macros, batch-processing, imagej

This is my second go at writing a macro (with virtually zero coding knowledge) after the first one was a success, but I am adding a layer of complexity that I can't seem to make functional.

I am trying to set up a batch process where I count particles of 2 different colors and then which of those particles is positive for both colors. I am getting this error:

Error:      ')' expected in line 38:
selectWindow ( "Result of "  - "+Title" ) ;

I really don't know what I need to fix because it seems that I have closed all open parentheses. However, I know that the root issue is that I don't know how to generically name the window I am interested in. It is a window that is created by the macro and is not one of the input files.

```
dir1 = getDirectory("Input"); 
dir2 = getDirectory("Output"); 
list = getFileList(dir1); 
run("Close All"); 
setBatchMode(true); 
for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) { 
 file1 = dir1 + list[i];
 file2 = dir2 + list[i];
 file3 = dir2 + list[i];
 file3 =  replace(file3, ".tif", ".csv");
 open(file1);
 Title = getTitle();
 Title = replace(Title, ".tif", "");
 run("Stack to Images");
 selectWindow(Title+"-0002");
 rename ("mNG-"+Title);
run("Subtract Background...", "rolling=50");
 setAutoThreshold("RenyiEntropy dark");
 //run("Threshold...");
 run("Convert to Mask");
 run("Fill Holes");
 run("Watershed");
run("Set Measurements...", "area mean min centroid center perimeter integrated median kurtosis area_fraction stack limit display redirect=None decimal=2");
run("Analyze Particles...", "size=9-475 circularity=0.50-1.00 show=Outlines display exclude summarize in_situ");
run("Fill Holes"); 
selectWindow(Title+"-0003");
 rename ("tdT-"+Title);
run("Subtract Background...", "rolling=50");
 setAutoThreshold("RenyiEntropy dark");
 //run("Threshold...");
 run("Convert to Mask");
 run("Fill Holes");
 run("Watershed");
run("Set Measurements...", "area mean min centroid center perimeter integrated median kurtosis area_fraction stack limit display redirect=None decimal=2");
run("Analyze Particles...", "size=9-475 circularity=0.50-1.00 show=Outlines display exclude summarize in_situ");
run("Fill Holes");
imageCalculator("Add create", "mNG-"+Title,"tdT-"+Title);
rename ("doublepositive"+Title)
selectWindow(Result of "mNG-"+Title);
run("Analyze Particles...", "size=9-475 circularity=0.50-1.00 show=Outlines display exclude summarize in_situ");
run("Images to Stack", "name=[] title=[] use");
 saveAs("Tiff", file2);
 run("Close All");
} 
setBatchMode(false); 
selectWindow("Summary");
saveAs("Results", "file3");
run("Close All");
```

If I could get help on why my syntax is wrong and also feedback on how to generically name the window with the third result, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I removed the line: rename ("doublepositive"+Title) which was missing the semicolon because I realized that line actually didn't lead anywhere. After removing that line I still get an error but now this is the error:

Comment: I don't know how to create the generic version of the name so that it will work for every file in the input. Here is the error:
getTitle() * "Result of mNG-cc8'22_mNG_tdT_B6_9dpi_008"
dir1 *"F:\Bethany\cc9'22\Input\"
dir2 *"F:\Bethany\cc9'22\Output\"
list *array[5]
i *0
file1 * "F:\Bethany\cc9'22\Input\cc8'22_mNG_tdT_B6_9dpi_008.tif"
file2 * "F:\Bethany\cc9'22\Output\cc8'22_mNG_tdT_B6_9dpi_008.tif"
file3 * "F:\Bethany\cc9'22\Output\cc8'22_mNG_tdT_B6_9dpi_008.csv"
Title * "cc8'22_mNG_tdT_B6_9dpi_008"
Error: ')' expected in line 38:
  selectWindow ( "Result of " <mNG> - "+Title" ) ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that you just have to change the whole name in to a string

```
selectWindow("Result of mNG-"+Title);
```

or

```
selectWindow("Result of "+"mNG-"+Title);
```

If this doesn't help, could you give me an example of your data so I can properly test it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Both of those option work! Also, I figured out if I delete that line entirely is also works. Who knew? Probably all of you brilliant coders.

Comment: Now that the macro works, I would like to add code to save the Results (with individual particle size data) and Summary data. I tried the code below but got this error: Unsupported save() or saveas() file format: "summary" "file3" 
If I take out all the file4 related language it works. 
`file3 = dir2 + list[i];
 file4 = dir2 + list[i];
 file3 =  replace(file3, ".tif", ".csv");
 file4 =  replace(file4, ".tif", ".csv");
 open(file1);`...
`setBatchMode(false); 
selectWindow("Summary");
saveAs("Summary", "file3");
selectWindow("Results");
saveAs("Results", "file4");
run("Close All");`

Comment: Regarding the first comment, it still works because that window is already selected, the last window you open/create in the one that is selected if you don't specify otherwise. But I think your way is great, because than you can be sure which window is selected.

The second comment, I haven't worked a lot with different save options. Check what happens if you remove "" around `file3` and `file4`, they are already strings, so they don't need "".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for all the help! @Petra and another person whose comment appears to have been deleted were super helpful! I have worked out the save issues. Here is the final code. It does work and generally yields good results. The resolution in some of my images isn't great so I do get a few false positives where 2 particles are very close and some unfocused light overlaps from the 2 signals, but I will continue to try to adjust things now that the macro totally works! :)
Here is the final code that I have been working with:

```
dir1 = getDirectory("Input"); 
dir2 = getDirectory("Output"); 
list = getFileList(dir1); 
run("Close All"); 
setBatchMode(true); 
for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) { 
 file1 = dir1 + list[i];
 file2 = dir2 + list[i];
 file3 = dir2 + list[i];
 file4 = dir2 + list[i];
 file3 =  replace(file3, ".tif", "Summary.csv");
 file4 =  replace(file4, ".tif", "Results.csv");
 open(file1);
 Title = getTitle();
 Title = replace(Title, ".tif", "");
 run("Stack to Images");
 selectWindow(Title+"-0001");
 rename ("mNG-"+Title);
run("Subtract Background...", "rolling=50");
 setAutoThreshold("RenyiEntropy dark");
 //run("Threshold...");
  setThreshold(400, 65535);
 run("Convert to Mask");
 run("Fill Holes");
 run("Watershed");
run("Set Measurements...", "area mean min centroid center perimeter integrated median kurtosis area_fraction stack limit display redirect=None decimal=2");
run("Analyze Particles...", "size=9-475 circularity=0.50-1.00 show=[Bare Outlines] display exclude summarize in_situ");
 run("Fill Holes"); 
 run("Watershed");
selectWindow(Title+"-0002");
 rename ("tdT-"+Title);
run("Subtract Background...", "rolling=50");
 setAutoThreshold("RenyiEntropy dark");
 //run("Threshold...");
 run("Convert to Mask");
 run("Fill Holes");
 run("Watershed");
run("Set Measurements...", "area mean min centroid center perimeter integrated median kurtosis area_fraction stack limit display redirect=None decimal=2");
run("Analyze Particles...", "size=9-475 circularity=0.50-1.00 show=[Bare Outlines] display exclude summarize in_situ");
 run("Fill Holes");
 run("Watershed");
imageCalculator("ADD create","mNG-"+Title,"tdT-"+Title);
run("Analyze Particles...", "size=9-475 circularity=0.50-1.00 show=Outlines display exclude summarize in_situ");
run("Images to Stack", "name=[] title=[] use");
 saveAs(".tif", file2);
 run("Close All");
} 
setBatchMode(false); 
selectWindow("Summary");
saveAs("text", file3);
selectWindow("Results");
saveAs("text", file4);
run("Close All");
```

Thanks again for all the help!